# undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.closeDrawer()') error in react native app

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am beginner of react native. I am using NativeBase Components for designing. When I use drawer app giving this error

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.closeDrawer()')
```

**This is screenshot of error**

[image]

**Drawer Code is here**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Drawer } from 'native-base';
import SideBar from './sidebar';
import Signup from './signup';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default class NativeDrawer extends Component {
  render() {
    closeDrawer = () => {
      this.drawer._root.close()
    };
    openDrawer = () => {
      this.drawer._root.open()
    };
    return (
      <View>

        <Drawer
          ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
          content={<SideBar navigator={this.navigator} />}
          onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >
        </Drawer>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**SideBar code is here**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class SideBar extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
                <Text>
                    Hello World
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Other NativeBase components are working but Drawer is giving an error

Answer (score 6):

You are setting the prop `onClose` for your `<Drawer>` component by using a reference to `this.closeDrawer`.

This will look for the definition of `closerDrawer` on your component **but you have defined it within your `render` method**.

Defining `closeDrawer` in the scope of the Component should fix your issue (N.B. I've also moved `openDrawer` out of render as well):

```
export default class NativeDrawer extends Component {
  // Moved outside of render:
  closeDrawer = () => {
      this.drawer._root.close()
  };

  openDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.open()
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <View>
        <Drawer
          ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
          content={<SideBar navigator={this.navigator} />}
          onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >
        </Drawer>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: After using this its work but not showing anything, showing just a white screen

Comment: @Bikash: If you're having similar problems and would like some insight that has not been clarified here, you could try posting a question about your issues raising the specific points that pertain to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most simple: just remove the "this." in front of closeDrawer()

I'm running the same example code and that fixed it for me!